# Difference between selection sort and just normally sorting using two loops

Tags: python, sorting

I know that the time complexity of selection sort is O(n^2) and the space complexity is O(1). But I can get the same complexity by just using two loops, which makes sorting straightforward. Can someone explain to me why I would prefer selection sort instead?

**SELECTION SORT**

```
def selectionSort(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        idx_min = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
            if nums[j] < nums[idx_min]:
                idx_min = j
        nums[idx_min], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[idx_min]
    return nums
```

**Ordinary sort using two loops**

```
def sort(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
            if nums[j] < nums[i]:
                  nums[j], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[j]
    return nums
```

Comment: Your ordinary sort seems like an example of Bubble sort. They are just two different ways of sorting with the similar time & space complexities. Maybe this'll help? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort-vs-bubble-sort/

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the second one is bubble sort, hadn't looked at it.

Comment: No, the second sort is definitely ***not*** bubble sort. Bubble sort only swaps adjacent elements. The second sort can swap elements at any two positions i, j with i < j.

Comment: The main question is: how do you count the complexity? In number of comparisons, or in number of swaps? Your selection sort performs about n²/2 comparisons `nums[j] < nums[idx_min]`, but only `n-1` swaps `nums[idx_min], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[idx_min]`. Your "ordinary sort" performs n²/2 comparisons `nums[j] < nums[i]`, and also up to n²/2 swaps `nums[j], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[j]`. Your "ordinary" sort looks pretty similar to selection sort, except it performs extra swaps to avoid variable `idx_min`.

Comment: @votelessbubble It's [exchange sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Exchange_sort).

Comment: @Stef Also seems like the `if` condition is true [far more often](https://tio.run/##pVLLboMwELzzFXsExVUx7SGKwlf0GKGqKnZjBGu0NlL79dSvQhDtoYoPa3t3Zjy78vhlrxqfjiPNcyskGNGLd6s0vmiyOU6DKU4ZuGVpEgZqKMNNagIFCoHe8EPkvcCIfeAJ7pdqP18Hh6lBLTlP7FaiggNwBgv/hh0UJPj0pWvgHE9Js9niVoOHGviutBrpltpGjaVr4yDpxLaIwCNhJ8L4UpaFcd0/pbsn8r9ZJPbfHXe/9SpJD95g6zY1jK5rMNdJyl5k3j96/7wsSwZViM8hHl2M5ryye6lXxuaxTyyKUEkysdl1htyh93/xcmpuMJXH7EojKXQplnTSXv3sjzFdzPM3) for the exchange sort than for the selection sort. So not only is the swap more costly than the index update, but it also happens more often.